# Issues in jquery faq page in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftcps9yr/):

When i click the first question it shows answer, at the same time, when i click the same first question again, it didn't hide the answer. but all other functions working fine. How can I fix this?

html:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li>
      <h3>How long does Liquid Rubber Waterproof Sealant take to cure?</h3>

      <div class="panel">
        <p>Liquid Rubber Waterproof Sealant is waterbased and curing is dependant on temperature, air movement and humidity.  In normal temperatures of 20 °C (68°F), 1 mm (40 mil, 0.0394") will take approximately 6 - 8 hours.  Please keep in mind the thicker the product is applied in 1 coat, the curing time goes up exponentially.  It is best to do lighter coats and build up your thickness.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>How thick should my final membrane be of Liquid Rubber Waterproof Sealant?</h3>

      <div class="panel">
        <p>Liquid Rubber Waterproof Sealant final dry film thickness (DFT) will vary depending on the application.  Generally for horizonatal/flat waterproofing you will want a minimum of 2mm (80 mil, 0.0787") DFT.  Coverage is approximately 3.34L / 1 sq. m. or 12 sq. ft. / 1G.  For vertical applications you will want a minimum of 1.5mm (60 mil, 0.0591") DFT.  Coverage is approximately 2.5L / 1 sq. m. or 16 sq. ft. / 1G.  For constant ponding/submersion you will want upwards of 3mm (120 mil, 0.118").  Coverage is approximately 5L / 1 sq. M. or 8 sq. ft. / 1G.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>How should I prepare the surface?</h3>

      <div class="panel">
        <p>Apply to a dry surface which is free of dirt, debris, oil, grease, coal tar, efflorescence, flaking paint, silicone, solvenated materials or other contaminants.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
        <li>
      <h3>How do I cover gaps and cracks?</h3>

      <div class="panel">
        <p>Liquid Rubber Seam Tape (add link http://liquidrubber.ca/collections/products-page/products/seam-tape) is used to bridge gaps, cracks, seams, vents, protrusions…..</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.stop()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container li").click(function() {
    $('#container li div').slideUp();
    $('#container li span').text('+');
    $(this).find('.panel').stop().slideToggle(); // add .stop() here 
    $(this).find('span').text('-');
  });
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/ftcps9yr/4/

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container li").click(function() {
    // $('#container li div').slideUp();
    // $('#container li span').text('+');
    $(this).find('.panel').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('span').text('-');
  });
});
```

That is, I commented out the first two line.

Is the idea that you are trying to close a div a previous click opened?  You need to do that some other way.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is event propagation :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('.panel').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ftcps9yr/6/